# как проверить в java, подключен ли компьютер к wi-fi мобильного устройства?

Tags: java, wifi, desktop

Мне нужно перед передачей данных по сети проверить, не подключен ли комп/ноут к вай-фаю, который раздаётся смартфоном (не важно, каким), чтобы предупредить пользователя, что за передачу трафика могут взиматься деньги.
Я думаю получать информацию о точке доступа, к которой комп подключен, и там выискивать, что за девайс предоставляет точку доступа. Такое вообще возможно реализовать? Есть ли какие-либо инструменты, библиотеки в джаве для всего этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчет явы не знаю, но можно выполнить пару команд.

Выполни `route print` и посмотри шлюз по умолчанию. Есть типовые адреса для точек доступа мобильного, например, 192.168.43.1.

Выполни `arp -a` и посмотри мак адрес шлюза - по нему можно получить производителя устройства

Попробуй просканировать порты на шлюзе, на роутерах 23,80 порты или закрыто всё

На телефонах часто запущен 5060 (для звонков по вайфай) и много других https://www.ndss-symposium.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/ndss2019_06B-5_Wu_paper.pdf

Можно ещё запросить днс адрес, на который роутер не ответит.

```
nslookup ip6-localhost 192.168.43.1
```

---

Но лучше всего попробовать определить оператора связи по внешнему ip адресу.

```
nslookup 213.87.137.166
166.137.87.213.in-addr.arpa name = 166.gprs.mts.ru.
```

или через whois

```
https://www.whois.com/whois/109.197.204.31

descr:          PJSC "VimpelCom"
origin:         AS16345
```

Comment: Спасибо, покопаюсь!